# 3G modem not being detected after instaling V mobile broadband

Tags: mobile-broadband

I have 3G mobile broadband(Visiontek 7.2 HSUPA modem with AIRCEL simcard) which was very well detected and able to browse Internet in Ubuntu 12.04 previously.

Unfortunately I have installed V mobile broadband(bcm software) out of enthusiasm,after that mobile broadband is not being shown up in network manager.

Even after complete removal of V mobile broadband also 3G modem is not being detected.

Comment: What's the output of lsusb?

Comment: Need more information... Is your device Huwawei? How did you uninstalled it?

Comment: Its Huawei device since I too have same problem I can explain more about it. I have installed same mobile partner software for linux and it can be unistalled using unistall option coming along with the program but even after unistalling it modem manager fails to detect the modem. But this works fine using sakis3g.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can install Sakis3g , this is a 3g manager and this may work to solve your problem.

Note that, to do this you will need to uninstall usb-modeswitch.

Open a terminal window, and type these commands:

```
sudo bash

cd /usr/bin

wget 'http://www.sakis3g.org/versions/latest/sakis3g.gz'
```

Then, type this:

```
gunzip sakis3g.gz

chmod +x sakis3g
```

Run sakis3g from the terminal window:

```
sakis3g
```

Take a look through the menus , and optimize to your needs.

Hope it helps and solve your problem.

Comment: This doesnt solve the issue, but will help in connecting 3g. Modem manager stil fails to detect the modem.

Answer (score 0):

*V mobile broadband* may conflict with `modem-manager` and may be removed from your system.

Ensure `modem-manager` is installed by checking
`which modem-manager` or
If unsure run
`sudo apt-get install modem-manager`